# How can I use Mandrill App as system message mailer on Parallels Panel?

Tags: email, centos, postfix-mta, parallels, mandrill

Currently I have my CentOS system set up with Parallels Panel and have my mailing system working nicely. But I'd prefer to have my system messages to be mailed using Mandrill App (MailChimp guys).

I have it working now with a kind of a mixed setup. Simple, though working. But now I get an error in my mail logs saying the following:

```
Jan  4 10:41:11 shinjuku postfix/smtp[29469]: certificate verification failed for smtp.mandrillapp.com[46.137.69.113]:25: untrusted issuer /C=ZA/ST=Western Cape/L=Cape Town/O=Thawte Consulting cc/OU=Certification Services Division/CN=Thawte Premium Server CA/emailAddress=premium-server@thawte.com`
```

After this I've tried configuring the `smtp_tls_CApath` and `smtpd_tls_CApath` to point to `/etc/ssl/certs`, but still no luck on this part.
Does someone have an idea on how I can get this working to have ALL system messages to be sent using Mandrill, instead of built-in config?

Answer (score 3):

Mark, for CentOS try this for your CAPath/CAfile

```
smtp_tls_CAfile = /etc/ssl/certs/ca-bundle.crt
```